# fail2ban doesn't ban IP, but says to do it

Tags: security, firewall, iptables, fail2ban

I've fail2ban 0.9.6 working with iptables 1.6.2, and I'm using it to block an attacker that, since some days, has been teasing my email server (the typical Dovecot + Postfix installation). Everything works, config files, log files, etc. but it doesn't really ban the IP address of the attacker, because I can see him trying to access in /var/log/mail.log, even after fail2ban banned it.

This is an extract from the log, from this attacker:

```
Oct 27 00:05:55 servidor dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd-file(jade@de-chile.cl,92.118.38.54): lookup: user=jade@de-chile.cl file=/etc/passwd-file
Oct 27 00:05:55 servidor dovecot: auth: passwd-file(jade@de-chile.cl,92.118.38.54): unknown user (given password: password)
Oct 27 00:05:57 servidor dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL#0111#011user=jade@de-chile.cl
Oct 27 00:05:57 servidor postfix/smtps/smtpd[2047]: warning: unknown[92.118.38.54]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Oct 27 00:06:06 servidor postfix/smtps/smtpd[2047]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[92.118.38.54]
Oct 27 00:06:06 servidor postfix/smtps/smtpd[2047]: disconnect from unknown[92.118.38.54] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 commands=2/3
```

He has tried with many usernames, and always the same passwords. This is was fail2ban-client status says, however:

```
$ sudo fail2ban-client status dovecot-pop3imap
Status for the jail: dovecot-pop3imap
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed:     16
|  `- File list:        /var/log/mail.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     1
   `- Banned IP list:   92.118.38.54

$ sudo fail2ban-client status postfix-sasl
Status for the jail: postfix-sasl
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed:     17
|  `- File list:        /var/log/mail.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned:     0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

Idk why the IP is banned in dovecot-pop3imap but not in postfix-sasl (is it feature? not to repeat the same ban in different profiles?)

This is my /etc/fail2ban/jail.local file:

```
 # Configuración pensada para usarse junto con iptables

 # RESOURCES:
 # * https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fail2ban
 # * https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/Fail2Ban
 # * https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_fail2ban_spanish
 # * https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security/
 # * https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Fail2ban
 # * https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTOs

 [DEFAULT]
 bantime = 3600
 destemail = d@de-chile.cl
 sender = d@de-chile.cl

 # to ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
 action = %(action_mw)s

 # same as action_mw but also send relevant log lines
 #action = %(action_mwl)s

 maxretry = 5

 # Dovecot
 [dovecot-pop3imap]
 enabled = true
 filter = dovecot-pop3imap
 action = iptables-multiport[name=dovecot, port="pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps", protocol=tcp]
 logpath = /var/log/mail.log
 #maxretry = 5
 findtime = 1200
 #bantime = 3600

 # Postfix
 [postfix]
 enabled = true
 filter = postfix
 action = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,submissions,submission", protocol=tcp]
 logpath = /var/log/mail.log
 #maxretry = 5
 #bantime = 3600

 [postfix-sasl]
 enabled = true
 filter = postfix-sasl
 action = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,submissions,submission", protocol=tcp]
 logpath = /var/log/mail.log
 #maxretry = 5
 #bantime = 3600

 [postfix-rbl]
 enabled = true
 filter = postfix-rbl
 action = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,submissions,submission",p rotocol=tcp]
 logpath = /var/log/mail.log
 #maxretry = 5
 #bantime = 3600
```

Info from iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -nvL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4881 packets, 247K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       95 12521 f2b-dovecot  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995,143,993
2     2697  133K f2b-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587
3     2697  133K f2b-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587
4     2698  133K f2b-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 23063 packets, 1114K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain f2b-dovecot (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       92.118.38.54         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2       95 12521 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-postfix (3 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     8092  398K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

P.S: I don't want to manually block this specific IP because I want the banning process to be automatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it looks like the `Currently failed: 1` meant something :P

Looks like the problem was the `action` in profiles, so I finally solved it by using some default settings for it, this is my new `jail.local` file:

```
# Configuración pensada para usarse junto con iptables

##############
# RESOURCES: #
##############
# * https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fail2ban
# * https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/Fail2Ban
# * https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_fail2ban_spanish
# * https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security/
# * https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Fail2ban
# * https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTOs

[DEFAULT]
# bantime for 1 day
bantime = 86400
destemail = d@de-chile.cl
sender = noreply-fail2ban@de-chile.cl
backend = pyinotify

# if the guy fails 5 times in 1/2 hour, gets banned
findtime = 1800
maxretry = 5

# to ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
#action = %(action_mw)s

# same as action_mw but also send relevant log lines
action = %(action_mwl)s

############
# PROFILES #
############

# Se asume que banaction = iptables-multiport

# Dovecot
[dovecot-pop3imap]
enabled = true
filter = dovecot-pop3imap
port = pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps
#action = iptables-multiport[name=dovecot, port="pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/mail.log

# Postfix
[postfix]
enabled = true
filter = postfix
port = smtp,submissions,submission
#action = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,submissions,submission", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/mail.log

[postfix-sasl]
enabled = true
filter = postfix-sasl
port = smtp,submissions,submission,pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps
#action = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,submissions,submission", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/mail.warn

[postfix-rbl]
enabled = true
filter = postfix-rbl
port = smtp,submissions,submission
#action = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,submissions,submission", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/mail.log
```